# Python Tornado too many files open

Tags: python, nginx, tornado

I have tornado websocket server, and nginx in front of it. My files open files limit is set to 1000000, and I still get the following error:

```
file "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 206, in accepterror: [Errno 24]  Too many open files
```

When I run `sudo sysctl -p` I get `fs.file-max = 1000000`.

There is no way that limit was reached, because server was up and running for only 12 hours (100-200 sessions)

What could be causing this error?

Comment: inspect limits of the process `cat /proc/PID_OF_THE_PROCESS/limits`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the detail information by `lsof`, to see which `process` or `socket` use up your `fd`

Answer (score 0):

Tried the solution of following StackOverflow topic ?

[socket.accept error 24: To many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569620/socket-accept-error-24-to-many-open-files)

Answer (score 0):

`fs.file-max` is a system-wide limit. There is also a per-process limit (much smaller by default, often 1024 or less). The per-process limit is controlled by `/etc/security/limits.conf` or the `ulimit` command.