# Fast API call out of system resource error

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi, uvicorn

I have build an an application for some processing & its code has been wrapped by using fast api so that other people can use the processing i.e. the functionality. The api accepts only 2 inputs & returns a single json output. The code works fine till 500 hits to the api after that the following error starts to show up in log file :
[image]

FASTAPI version == 0.68.1

Code structure:
[image]

Comment: Seems you are opening lots of files (sockets are files) and not closing these. Or the account from which the process is launched has limited number of opened files.

Comment: Please do not include relevant details as images - they're not accessible and not searchable. Since this also seems to be a code problem, the relevant code should be included. It seems from your exception that you have to many open sockets - check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569620/socket-accept-error-24-to-many-open-files for further details.